# Equally spaced contours on a Bar Legend

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending

The function `BarLegend[{"Rainbow",{0,1}},4]` should result in a bar legend with range 0 to 1 with 4 equally spaced contours.

I was hoping to get contours at `{0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}` but found them at `{0.19,0.38,0.57,0.76}` which are equally spaced but don't properly span the range

How should i go about getting the result i expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, {Automatic, 5}]
```

[image]

You can also use [FindDivisions$[\{x_{min}, x_{max}\}, n]$](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindDivisions.html) to get ***a list of about* n *"nice" numbers that divide the interval around* $x_{min}$ *to* $x_{max}$ *into equally spaced parts*** to specify the contours list

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, FindDivisions[{0, 1}, 5]]
```

> same picture

You can also use a list of contours in the second argument:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1}}, Subdivide[5]]
```

> same picture